# WP7: How to block click event on Grid when clicking on child control?

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, click

I wrote my own checkbox ContentControl for better design control.

**What the scenario looks like:**

I got a Listbox with custom templated list items, which, in turn, have a text item and my custom checkbox.

**Wanted behaviour:**

- clicking on the list item changes page to a detailed view of that item.
- clicking the checkbox only toggles the checkmark on it and does not trigger the page change.

**Actual behaviour:**

You may guess, when clicking on my checkbox, the page change event is still fired.

**How I implemented that:**

My checkbox has a Grid, which holds a Rectangle and an Icon. I bound a Tap event to the Grid, to toggle the IsChecked status. (Grid objects don't have a click event).

Is it because I'm not using a click event? If so, which interface does my ContentControl have to implement for it? Or how does the default Checkbox (Button?) control manage that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote my own checkbox ContentControl for better design control

If you feel you really must create your own CheckBox, your control should extend ToggleButton. This will give you the behavior you want. I would be really surprised if the standard checkbox does not work for you. You can change the style of the checkbox to do whatever you want, change to whatever you want. I am doing exactly what you are wanted to do and it's works great. I use a checkbox within the `ItemTemplate` of a `ListBox`. I have styled the checkbox to have a different look then the regular checkbox. Here is a sample of my ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         SelectionChanged="Stations_SelectionChanged"
         toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
         SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,17">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding YesOrNo, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="48"
                          Style="{StaticResource MinimalCheckBoxStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherProperty}"
                           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"
                           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I will look into the ToggleButton, thanks. Also, could you post the code where you defined your Resource "MinimalChecboxStyle"? That would help me a lot. What properties can be set for a control's style?

Comment: You can set any property. Here is the [standard formatting for checkbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278078(v=VS.95).aspx). You also may want to check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163497.aspx)